# How to get cheese melted without burning grilled cheese

Tags: cheese, grilling, sandwich

I've been using a George Foreman like grill for grilled cheese sandwiches. The problem is the bread seems to burn before the cheese is thoroughly melted. How can I fix this? Do I just need to add more butter because I've been trying that.

EDIT: I keep my cheese in the refrigerator so maybe leaving it on the counter to come to room temperature would help.

Comment: Lower the heat.

Comment: Do it in a pan, then you don't end up with grilled cheese melba toast, _and_ the bread doesn't burn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a model that allows you to change the temperature?  If so, lower the heat.  I prefer medium to medium low heat for grilled cheese.  It gives time for the cheese to melt, and the slow cooking means the bread toasts through more without burning the surface touching the pan.

[Here is a list of temperatures](http://www.smartkitchen.com/resources/cooking-appendices/reference-materials/heat-temperature-charts).  I am not sure what the lowest setting on a FG is (assuming it is adjustable), but I would guess it is in the medium and up range.

If not, you may want to just use a pan.  I love my Forman Grill (got it for xmas over a decade ago and use it often), but it is good for specific things.  A great grilled cheese is not one of them.  Also, you are cooking it on both sides at once.  Normally you have n * 2 minutes to melt the cheese as the bread toasts; you only get n or somewhere around that when using the FG.

Comment: No it doesn't have a temperature control. I'm beginning to find the Foreman isn't well suited for many things, what do you find it works well with?

Comment: Pretty much just uniform hunks of carcass.  Pork loin steaks, beef steaks, chicken breasts, burgers, fish, etc.  I have cooked mushrooms in it before.  If you have the space for a gas grill it will work better, but living in the PNW, there are enough rainy days that it is easier to just use the FG.  I have made Moose-burgers in it a couple times; probably the most unique thing I cooked with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different cheese that melts better; try Gouda, Gruyère, Jalsberg or similar. Most Swiss cheese melts well.